# Problem with MacPorts

Tags: macports, xcode

I have MacPorts installed on my Mac and a lot of ports that were put on my machine years ago by my sysadmin for various purposes. There is quite a lot of garbage out there, but worst of all, the MacPorts system itself is fried.

My immediate desire is to upgrade subversion via MacPorts. When I try to use MacPorts to update itself (sudo port -d selfupdate), I get an inscrutable error message referring to "the log" but it does not indicate which log, as it often does.

After some hacking with -d and poking around at likely logs, it appears that the cc compiler is missing or failing. I have XCode 4.5.2 installed so I am wondering why this issue is occurring.

Bottom line: I am looking for a way to fix MacPorts; then eventually update everything, clean up the inactive ports, and finally make sure subversion is updated.

I am wondering about these possible steps:

1. Uninstall/reinstall Xcode.
2. Uninstall/reinstall MacPorts. The instructions for this seem to indicate that all installed ports will be removed, which is scary as I am not sure what that would break, but it would probably break something.

Are these possible corrective paths? Or is there something less drastic?

Comment: The macports log does tell you which is the next log to look at - please give the complete error message line - However in this case the issue is not having the Xcode command line tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line tools are no more bundled with Xcode by default (since). Instead, they can be installed optionally using the Components tab of the Downloads preferences panel.

Comment: Installing the command line tools fixed the problem. Thanks!